# IMAPFolder getSortedMessages not working with Liferay/Tomcat but working with regular Java application

Tags: java, email, tomcat, jakarta-mail

I am trying to create an API endpoint to fetch emails for a particular user through Liferay/Tomcat. This is the code I wrote using Java Mail:

```
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, null);
session.setDebug(false);

try {
    Store store = session.getStore(protocol);
    store.connect(host, userName, password);
    // opens the inbox folder
    // Folder folderInbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
    IMAPFolder folderInbox = (IMAPFolder) store.getFolder("INBOX");
    folderInbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

    // fetches new messages from server
    SortTerm[] sortTerms = new SortTerm[2];
    sortTerms[0] = SortTerm.REVERSE;
    sortTerms[1] = SortTerm.DATE;
    // getSortedMessages does not work
    Message[] messages = folderInbox.getSortedMessages(sortTerms);
    // getMessages works
    // Message[] messages = folderInbox.getMessages();

    int msgCount = folderInbox.getUnreadMessageCount();
    LOGGER.error("msgCount - {}", msgCount);

} catch (NoSuchProviderException ex) {
    LOGGER.error("No provider for protocol: " + protocol);
} catch (MessagingException ex) {
    LOGGER.error("Could not connect to the message store");
} catch (Exception e) {
    LOGGER.error("some other error");
}
```

I have imported javax.mail in my pom.xml file. I am trying to use the getSortedMessages to fetch the newest emails first. I repeatedly get a:
com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.getSortedMessages([Lcom/sun/mail/imap/SortTerm;)[Ljavax/mail/Message; method not found.

If I use the getMessages, it works fine, giving me the emails with the oldest first. However, when I place this code in a regular Java application (nothing to do with Spring or Tomcat or Liferay) with the javax.mail.jar and activation.jar resources in my classpath, the getSortedMessages works perfectly fine giving me the emails with the newest first.

I can't figure out what is missing in my Tomcat/Maven build? Do I need another dependency? Also, getMessages works perfectly fine with IMAPFolder and so do other methods like getUnreadMessageCount(). So it is not as if it can't find the IMAPFolder itself. Just the getSortedMessages has disappeared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me as that the JavaMail version that you used to compile your stuff, and that one coming/was installed with your Tomcat are not the same.

`SortTerm` came with JavaMail 1.4.4, as well as `IMAPFolder.getSortedMessages()`, so I assume that your Tomcat uses an older version.

Most probably, you ran your standalone code from within the IDE or by using the build tool, and there the version for the compilation is used.

Comment: Yes, could be. I use Java Mail 1.6.2. In my standalone, I just placed this 1.6.2 jar in the lib resources. So what can be done? Only option is to go back to 1.4.4 if I want these libs?

Comment: Which "lib resources"? Check the version of the library that is used when you run your code inside Tomcat. To do so, cast the `Store` instance to `IMAPStore` and print the `ID_VERSION` field.

Comment: In my standalone application, I created a lib directory where I put the javax.mail.jar and I added this directory in my IDE as a jar resource. In my Liferay/Tomcat, I used IMAPStore.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion() and this gives 1.4. Even when I have specified 1.6.2 in the Maven dependency.

Comment: @ShivKumar: you can run the `dependency:tree` Maven target to see which versions of the dependencies are resolved.

Comment: The Maven dependency is only relevant for a Maven run – means it is only active for the build or for a run of the application through Maven. And even if the JavaMail lib would be packaged to the WAR, if there is a JavaMail on the Tomcat level this one would be pulled first. So check your Tomcat installation (or Liferay installation, as Tomcat itself does not come with JavaMail OOTB).

Comment: Interestingly, this works without Tomcat/liferay when the only jar file is the javax.mail-1.6.2. So in the case of Tomcat, even if it uses 1.6.2, it could get into a conflict with another version altogether? Liferay comes with a mail.jar file which is the mail utility within Liferay. Maybe that might be causing the conflict?

Comment: @ShivKumar – Not "maybe"!! A class is searched for on all Jars on the CLASSPATH, starting with the first one on the list. The CLASSPATH for a web application is (very simplified!!) the CLASSPATH of the container *appended* by the CLASSPATH of the web application. So when there is a JavaMail already configured on the Container level and another one for the web application, always the Container wins. And the JVM searches classes only by name, versions are irrelevant (as long as they are not part of the name, of course). This will change a little bit when Jigsaw is more widely used.

Comment: I will need someone else in my office to help me out as Liferay is new to me. Will continue this on Monday most probably. Thanks a ton in the meantime.